# Laravel 5.5 - Change users password using API

Tags: laravel

I am looking into setting up password changing using the Laravel PassPort API.

I currently have it set so that an authenticated API call can be made containing the new password (hashed) and it is saved directly in the database overwriting the existing one.

Reading the docs I see mention of password reset tokens, my question is, do I need to worry about any of this?

I am already authenticating the user with their API token so is changing their password in this way correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is already authenticated then no, you don't need to worry about password reset tokens. These are only used when resetting the password by email.

Updating a password when the user is authenticated is as simple as

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->password = bcrypt(<the new password>);
$user->save();
```

Though this does not account for a pre hashed password, how are you hashing it on the client side? As the produced hash needs to use Laravel's app_key to work.